# PostgreSQL Query Help (Crosstab)

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have a table that looks like this:

| Project | Date | System | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | A | PASS |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | B | PASS |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | C | PASS |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | D | PASS |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | A | FAIL |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | B | FAIL |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | C | FAIL |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | D | FAIL |
| Proj2 | 07-01 | E | PASS |
| Proj2 | 07-01 | F | FAIL |
| Proj2 | 07-02 | E | PASS |
| Proj2 | 07-02 | F | PASS |

I want it to end up like this:

| Project | Date | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | PASS | PASS | PASS | PASS |  |  |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | FAIL | FAIL | FAIL | FAIL |  |  |
| Proj2 | 07-01 | PASS |  |  |  | PASS | FAIL |
| Proj2 | 07-02 | PASS |  |  |  | PASS | PASS |

I was also wondering if it was possible to produce something like this where the order of the various systems are just alphabetical.

| Project | Date | System1 | System2 | System3 | System4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | A-PASS | B-PASS | C-PASS | D-PASS |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | A-FAIL | B-FAIL | C-FAIL | D-FAIL |
| Proj2 | 07-01 | E-PASS | F-FAIL |  |  |
| Proj2 | 07-02 | E-PASS | F-PASS |  |  |

I have been trying for the last few days with the crosstab function and I am not able to reproduce the results I want. Any help would be much appreciated - thank you so much!

Comment: How does "System1", "System2" etc align with each row - why is `D-PASS` not under "System1"? Note - there is no ordering to a set of rows unless you can specify it.

Comment: @Stu I was planning it on being alphabetical

Answer (score 0):

Try the following without using `Crosstab`:

```
Select Project,Date_,
Max(Case When System_='A' Then Result_ Else '' End) As A,
Max(Case When System_='B' Then Result_ Else '' End) As B,
Max(Case When System_='C' Then Result_ Else '' End) As C,
Max(Case When System_='D' Then Result_ Else '' End) As D,
Max(Case When System_='E' Then Result_ Else '' End) As E,
Max(Case When System_='F' Then Result_ Else '' End) As F
From your_table
Group By Project,Date_
Order By Project,Date_
```

See a demo from *[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vUYSGQfqxSkhmd7tYGMXGs/0)*.

If the `System` column has an undetermined number of values (as you commented), then you have to use `Dynamic SQL`. I'm not proffenceinal in that, but the following will pay the bill:

First, create a function to prepare the dynamic statement as the following:

```
Create Or Replace Function pvt()
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
As $body$
Declare
    sqlColumn varchar;
    qr varchar;
    columnlist varchar;
Begin
    sqlColumn= 'select distinct system_ from your_table order by system_;';
    qr='prepare pvtstmt as Select Project,Date_,';
    
    For columnlist In EXECUTE sqlColumn  
      Loop
          qr = qr || 'Max(Case When System_='|| chr(39) || columnlist ||
          chr(39) ||' Then Result_ Else ' ||chr(39)||chr(39)||' End) As 
          ' ||  columnlist || ', ';
      End Loop;

    qr = substr(qr, 0, length(qr) - 1);
    qr = qr || 'From your_table Group By Project,Date_ Order By Project,Date_';
   
    Deallocate All;
    EXECUTE qr;
End;
$body$;
```

Now, call that function to create the prepared statement and execute that statement as the following:

```
Select pvt();
Execute pvtstmt;
```

Where `pvtstmt` is the name of the prepared statement in the function.

See a demo from *[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vUYSGQfqxSkhmd7tYGMXGs/2)*.

**Note**: in the demo, the label `$body$` is replaced with a single quote, just to run the function on the fiddle.

**For the second** version of the output format, (System1, System2,...) instead of system name, you may use a view that return `Row_Number() Over (Partition By Project,Date_ Order By System_)`. So the `pvt()` function will be as the following:

```
Create Or Replace Function pvt()
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
As $body$
Declare
    sqlColumn varchar;
    qr varchar;
    columnlist varchar;
Begin
    sqlColumn= 'select distinct D.sys_cat from (select Row_Number() Over (Partition By Project,Date_ Order By System_) as sys_cat From your_table) D order by D.sys_cat;';
    qr='prepare pvtstmt as Select D.Project,D.Date_,';
    
    For columnlist In EXECUTE sqlColumn  
      Loop
          qr=qr || ' Max(Case When sys_cat='|| chr(39) || columnlist || chr(39) ||' Then System_ ||' ||chr(39)||'-'||chr(39)||'|| Result_ Else ' ||chr(39)||chr(39)||' End) As System' ||  columnlist ||  ' , ';
      End Loop;

    qr = substr(qr, 0, length(qr) - 1);
    qr=qr || 'From (select *, Row_Number() Over (Partition By Project,Date_ Order By System_) as sys_cat From your_table) D Group By D.Project,D.Date_ Order By D.Project,D.Date_;';
   
    Deallocate All;
    EXECUTE qr;
End;
$body$;
```

Check this [*demo*](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vUYSGQfqxSkhmd7tYGMXGs/3).

Comment: Hey - this works perfectly! The only question I have is my actual database table is very large and it seems inefficient to list out each system as a new Case. Do you happen to know if there is an easier way?

Comment: @wadeland1738, in this case you have to use dynamic sql query, I will try to update the answer according to that.

Comment: awesome, I had never thought about using a dynamic query. If I wanted to include a filter (for ex. WHERE Project = 'Proj1'), where would I include that within the query?

Comment: Before the `Group by` of the outer query, `From ...
Where D.Project='Proj1'
Group By D.Project, D.Date_ Order By D.Project, D.Date_`

Comment: I tried that - it doesn't seem to work (not sure if I am missing something)

Comment: Check this, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vUYSGQfqxSkhmd7tYGMXGs/4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246895/discussion-between-wadeland1738-and-ahmed).

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, I just had one last question. Do you have experience with using Node/Express to set up an API with a dynamic query such as the one you have wrote? I am not sure how to reference the function correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, but I guess that all what you need is `Select pvt();
Execute pvtstmt;`, and you may use it as regular query.

Comment: Ok will try that out. Also, my WHERE clause is a little more complicated:

WHERE D.Project IN (SELECT D.Project FROM mapping WHERE Scenario = "Scenario1")

Do you know what the proper syntax would be (mapping is another table in my DB and scenario is a column in the mapping table)

Comment: "WHERE clause is a little more complicated", you may test it with non dynamic query before using it with the dynamic one, once it's Ok copy it to the dynamic one. Good Luck.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to store the result of the Execute statement in a table?

Comment: Dear, I can't answer all of your questions in the comments, post another question to get better answers.